# Preserve space in a string

Tags: bash, sed, ifs

$cat process-file.csv

```
"key1","key1-ConnString","Server=database.windows.net,1433;Database=sqldb;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

process-file.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
strip_quotes() {
   echo `sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' <<<"$1"`
}

while IFS=, read -r key1 keyC secretValue; do
 echo "$(strip_quotes $secretValue)"
done  < process-file.csv
```

```
$ ./process-file.sh
```

Server=database.windows.net,1433;Database=sqldb;Persist

How to preserve spaces in a string that needs the quote removed?

Comment: Check your script with http://shellcheck.net. I.e. remove all `echo` and quote variables.

Answer (score 1):

- Take out the backticks. (They shouldn't be used *at all* in code written for post-1992 shells; `$(...)` is the modern, POSIX-standardized way to do command substitution).
- Quote all your expansions. *All* of them. If you *do* need `$(something)`, then it needs to be `"($something)"` *with the quotes*. That's true of backticks too.
- Don't run `echo $(somecommand)` -- just run `somecommand`. It's faster, and it avoids the bugs that unquoted expansion (as referenced above) creates.

Fixing the above, but keeping your code's general structure, might look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
strip_quotes() {
   sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' <<<"$1"
}

while IFS=, read -r key1 keyC secretValue; do
 strip_quotes "$secretValue"
done  < process-file.csv
```

...but this is silly (and *extremely* slow), when you could run just one copy of `sed` to process the whole input file, instead of starting a new copy of `sed` for every individual line as your code currently does.

```
sed -re 's/^[^,]*,[^,]*,"(.*)"/\1/' <process-file.csv
```